# OpenDNS automatic diagnostics

Tags: shell-script, terminal, python, traceroute, nslookup

I've contacted OpenDNS support because advertising is not filtered on this  site http://www.backpackerboard.co.nz/

They asked me to read these manual instructions *[OpenDNS Diagnostic Tool: What to Provide Support When Asked](https://support.opendns.com/entries/21841580-Diagnostic-Tool-Link-and-Instructions#terminal)* and to run those commands on my terminal:

```
nslookup domain.com
nslookup domain.com 208.67.222.222
nslookup domain.com 208.67.220.220
nslookup domain.com 4.2.2.1
traceroute domain.com
```

and to send them back.

As I'm sure I will need to run those commands repeatedly in the future I would like to write a script. I'm studing **python** and I would like to make a

```
raw_input()
```

that asks for the URL and runs the requests but I don't know how to ask **python** to execute **shell commands**

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3777301/how-to-call-a-shell-script-from-python-code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution by myself and I've written a script:

```
from subprocess import call
target = str(raw_input("Give me a site: => "))

call(["nslookup", target]) % target
```

This is what I needed to know, thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

For Reference, tasks like this will not need to be repeated, because once OpenDNS investigates the information you return, you won't need to do it again unless you need to report multiple domains.  Your output will be similar to:

### Plain Lookup Using Your ISP's DNS

```
$ sudo nslookup backpackerboard.co.nz
Server:         66.90.132.162
Address:        66.90.132.162#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   backpackerboard.co.nz
Address: 199.229.248.91
```

---

### Match to OpenDNS DNS Server One

```
$ sudo nslookup backpackerboard.co.nz 208.67.222.222
Server:         208.67.222.222
Address:        208.67.222.222#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   backpackerboard.co.nz
Address: 199.229.248.91
```

---

### Match to OpenDNS DNS Server Two

```
$ sudo nslookup backpackerboard.co.nz 208.67.220.220
Server:         208.67.220.220
Address:        208.67.220.220#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   backpackerboard.co.nz
Address: 199.229.248.91
```

---

### Match to Level3 DNS Server

```
$ sudo nslookup backpackerboard.co.nz 4.2.2.1
Server:         4.2.2.1
Address:        4.2.2.1#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   backpackerboard.co.nz
Address: 199.229.248.91
```

---

### Reason this is Checked

I'll leave the `traceroute` to you, but the last hop should be `199.229.248.91`.  Since the IP's match in all four cases of `NSLookup`, OpenDNS will investigate the advertisements you claim they aren't blocking and will take action.  I just looked at the site in Chromium as I type this and I saw nothing that would flag attention.  If you're reporting the right hand sidebar, possibly nothing will change because those ads/tools are hosted by the site you are reporting.  OpenDNS only blocks content if the originating server is in the blacklist of known ad servers.

Interesting Tidbit: See [4.2.2.2: The Story Behind a DNS Legend](http://www.tummy.com/articles/famous-dns-server/)

Comment: I need to report multiple domains but more than ever I would like to learn how to ask python to run a "traceroute" or a "ping"